# Porting code from array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, char

I have developed a simple crossword generator where the important point is that I have used an array as the grid.  What I am working on now is setting it up so the user can choose what size grid they want to use.  With arrays I can not do that so I want to change my code to work with vectors.  I am having difficulty with that and tried a few different things but unable to get it working:

```
//    std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch;
//    std::vector<std::vector<char *> > wordsearch;
char wordsearch [10][11] = {0};
```

The third line is the array that functions properly with the code.  The first line crashes the program and the second line runs fine but complains about "invalid conversion from char to char* as I append characters to the vector.

I also tried

```
//    std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch_vector(wordsearch, wordsearch +     sizeof(wordsearch) / sizeof(char));
```

but it complains of char to char* conversion too.  In my other attempts I tried to write functions to convert array to vector but the array must be numerically defined in its dimensions, no variables or left unspecified for the user to later define such as:
std::vector > array_convertto_vector(array a); (array undefined)

Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int center_text(string string_word/*add second parameter if setw will vary*/) {
    int spaces = 10 - string_word.size();
    return spaces / 2;
}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    const char* const a_to_z = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ;

    int random_char;

//    std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch;
//    std::vector<std::vector<char *> > wordsearch;
    char wordsearch [10][11] = {0};

    int random_choice;
    int f_or_b;
    int random_word_number;
    int temp_i;
    int temp_j;

    string random_word;
    bool flag;


    string words_array[] = {"CAT", "HELLO", "GOODBYE", "DOG", "BAT", "NEW", "SAY", "MAY", "DAY", "HAY", "CELLO", "ORANGES", "LINK", "ROBIN"};
    vector<string> words_vector (words_array, words_array + sizeof(words_array) / sizeof(string));

    string words_found_array[] = {};
    vector<string> words_found_vector (words_found_array, words_found_array + sizeof(words_found_array) / sizeof(string));
    //vector<string> words_vector;
    //vector<string> words_found_vector;

//    ifstream myfile("Words.txt");
//    copy(istream_iterator<string>(myfile), istream_iterator<string>(),
//         back_inserter(words_vector)); //MAKE SURE TO LOAD INTO VECTOR ONLY ONCE, NOT EACH TIME PROGRAM LOADS!!!

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {

            random_choice = rand() % 5;
            f_or_b = rand() % 2;
            random_word_number = -1;
            if (words_vector.size() != 0) {
                random_word_number = rand() % words_vector.size();
                random_word = words_vector[random_word_number];
            }

            if (j == 10) {
                wordsearch[i][j] = '\n';
            }

            else if (wordsearch[i][j] != '\0') { // prevents overwriting horizontal words, or add to j in else if loop instead of temp_j
                continue;
            }

            else if (random_choice == 1 && random_word.size() < 11-j && words_vector.size() != 0) { //or <= 10-j
                flag = false;
                for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                    if (wordsearch[i][j+x] == random_word[x] || wordsearch[i][j+x] == '\0') {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                temp_j = j;
                if (flag == true) {
                    if (f_or_b == 1) { //reverse string
                        reverse(random_word.begin(), random_word.end());
                    }
                    for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                        wordsearch[i][temp_j] = random_word[x];
                        temp_j += 1;
                    }
                if (f_or_b == 1) { //reverse back
                    reverse(random_word.begin(), random_word.end());
                }
                words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);
                words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
                }
                else {
                    int random_char = rand() % 26 + 0;
                    wordsearch[i][j] = a_to_z[random_char];
                }
            }

            else if (random_choice == 2 && random_word.size() <= 10-i && words_vector.size() != 0) {
                flag = false;
                for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                    if (wordsearch[i+x][j] != '\0') {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                    if (wordsearch[i+x][j] == random_word[x] || wordsearch[i+x][j] == '\0') {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                temp_i = i;
                if (flag == true) {
                    if (f_or_b == 1) {
                        reverse(random_word.begin(), random_word.end());
                    }
                    for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                        wordsearch[temp_i][j] = random_word[x];
                        temp_i += 1;
                }
                if (f_or_b == 1) {
                    reverse(random_word.begin(), random_word.end());
                }
                words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);
                words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
                }
                else {
                    int random_char = rand() % 26 + 0;
                    wordsearch[i][j] = a_to_z[random_char];
                }
            }

            else if (random_choice == 3 && random_word.size() <= 10-i && random_word.size() < 11-j && words_vector.size() != 0) { //or <= 10-j
                flag = false;
                for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                    if (wordsearch[i+x][j+x] == random_word[x] || wordsearch[i+x][j+x] == '\0') {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                temp_i = i;
                temp_j = j;
                if (flag == true) {
                    if (f_or_b == 1) {
                        reverse(random_word.begin(), random_word.end());
                    }
                    for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                        wordsearch[temp_i][temp_j] = random_word[x];
                        temp_i += 1;
                        temp_j += 1;
                    }
                    if (f_or_b == 1) {
                        reverse(random_word.begin(), random_word.end());
                    }
                  words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);
                  words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
                }
                else {
                    int random_char = rand() % 26 + 0;
                    wordsearch[i][j] = a_to_z[random_char];
                }
            }

            else if (random_choice == 4 && random_word.size() <= 10-i && random_word.size() > 11-j && words_vector.size() != 0) { //or >= 10-j
                flag = false;
                for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                    if (wordsearch[i+x][j-x] == random_word[x] || wordsearch[i+x][j-x] == '\0') {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                temp_i = i;
                temp_j = j;
                if (flag == true) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                        wordsearch[temp_i][temp_j] = random_word[x];
                        temp_i += 1;
                        temp_j -= 1;
                }
                words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);
                words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
                }
                else {
                    int random_char = rand() % 26 + 0;
                    wordsearch[i][j] = a_to_z[random_char];
                }
            }

            else {
                    int random_char = rand() % 26 + 0;
                    wordsearch[i][j] = a_to_z[random_char];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                cout<<wordsearch[i][j];
        }
    }


//    std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch_vector;
//    std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch_vector(wordsearch, wordsearch + sizeof(wordsearch) / sizeof(char));

    random_shuffle(words_found_vector.begin(), words_found_vector.end());
    cout<<endl<<"Your words are:"<<endl;
    int counter = 0;
    int space_value;
    for (int x = 0; x < words_found_vector.size(); x++) {
        space_value = center_text(words_found_vector[x]);
        if (counter == 2) {
            for (int y = 0; y < space_value; y++) {
                cout<<" ";
            }
            cout<<words_found_vector[x]<<endl;
            counter = 0;
        }
        else {
            for (int y = 0; y < space_value; y++) {
                cout<<" ";
            }
            cout<<words_found_vector[x];
            counter += 1;
            for (int y = 0; y < space_value; y++) {
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You have to uncomment the vector portion and comment out the array portion in the three lines I singled out to make it work if I did not make the code clear enough.

Theres a part where I loaded in a file with words so I had to uncomment that part out.  If it still does not compile because of it let me know and I'll repost a hopefully working version of the code.  And thank you for your help!

Comment: IMHO, you are too much attached to the C thinking. You need to shift your paradigm when making such a change from a low-level language to OOP. In other words, why don't you just stick to list<string>?

Comment: That made me chuckle because I never did C, in fact I'm relatively new to C++.  Also what do you mean by list<string>?  I prefer vectors because I can dynamically change its size if a user wants to and it is similar to arrays which I am familiar with.  I don't know lists yet.  And I am always dealing with one character at a time, so char as opposed to string seemed natural.

Comment: A `main()` that's *216 lines long?* If you break this up into functions, you'll get something much easier to work with.

Comment: Instead of using `words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);` you could probably use `words_found_vector.push_back(words_vector[random_word_number]);`. [Push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is less typing and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your wordsearch vector so that it is the correct size. Otherwise your program attempts to use memory that was not allocated and (usually) gets a segment fault.

You can initialize a vector to a certain size by using the second constructor on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector.

Remember that you need to initialize the "inner" vectors as well.

For your particular use case, the correct code is:

`std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch(10,std::vector<char>(11));`

Note that you are initializing the wordsearch vector with 10 vectors of length 11.

Comment: I understand but the thing is that I want the user to define its size, not have its size hard-coded, unless the vector will still dynamically shrink or expand at runtime.  And if I use char as the type the program crashes, char* works but it complains of char to char* conversion.  Any ideas why it crashes or how to deal with char to char* conversion? It first comes up at             if (j == 10) {
                wordsearch[i][j] = '\n';
            }

Comment: @user2671156 Are you sure the char* version is actually compiling? It should fail for the same reason: attempting to use memory that is not allocated because the size of the vector is not set. The char to char* conversion is marked by the compiler because there is no built in conversion to turn a pointer (char*) into a number/character (char). They are separate types that cannot be assigned to one another (without perhaps using * or & operators).

Comment: @user2671156 As for setting the size during runtime you have two options:
1. Setting the size in the constructor by using a variable instead of the number literals. 2 Setting the size after construction using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: As for Beta who commented on the main(), I know this was just a quick and dirty build to try it out.  Once I get this vector issue resolved I'll break it down better. For //    string words_found_array[] = {};
//    vector<string> words_found_vector (words_found_array, words_found_array + sizeof(words_found_array) / sizeof(string)); , am I defining a size for the vector too?

Comment: @user2671156 I think you are just initializing the vector to a size of zero (because that array is of size zero). This isn't really that helpful because vectors automatically start with a size of zero. You are not encountering issues because vector::insert automatically increases the size as necessary.

Comment: Lalaland, I have done a quick implementation of your option 1 using your given code and it is working.  However when I run my iterations and such where I hard coded 10 and 11 such as in     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {      I need to change it to size of both dimensions in the vector.  That is why it may be crashing for me.  Would you happen to know what keywords I need to access the values of the vector dimensions?

Comment: @user2671156 [vector::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) will tell you the number of elements in each vector. In order to get the number of elements in the inner vector you can just call wordsearch[i].size() (or wordsearch[0].size() if you know each row is the same length).

Comment: Thanks Lalaland.  It works in my quick coding and I have made it work with my class for generating random wordsearches.  It gets a bit finicky when I tried to do this in my class:                    class WordSearch_ClassHeader
{
    private:
        int dimension;
        std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch(dimension,std::vector<char>(dimension)); where it complains dimension does not name a type. This works though     private:
        int dimension;
        std::vector<std::vector<char> > wordsearch(int a,std::vector<char>(int b)); and I set a=dim and b=dim+1 in a member function.